# How to access the dialog button in the preference dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have created a preference activity that has a dialog. The dialog has two buttons CANCEL and ADD. upon the click of the add button another dialog should open that has two edit text box's for entering the MAC address and the Device Name

How can  I handle the on Click of the button in the preference screen dialog. If I can access the on click of the dialog then I can open another activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply your own `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` for every default button of a dialog. Here's a copy-paste from the [Dialogs topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons) on developer.android.com:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MyActivity.this.finish();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Alternatively you can [create your own dialog, with a custom layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) displaying whatever widgets you like. Using this approach you can hook up regular `View.OnClickListener` to buttons and put the logic in there.

Comment: will try this out thakyou for the reply